# comparision between array column values with normal column values in hive

Tags: arrays, hadoop, hive

### Table1

```
Column1 Column2
1       1,2,10
2       11,12,13
3       1,2,14
4       20,1,10
5       11,12,13,14
```

### Table 2

```
Column1 Column2
1       Purchase
2       Product View
10      Cart Open
11      Checkout
12      Cart Add
13      Cart Remove
14      Cart View
20      Campaign View
```

### Result table should come like below

```
Column1 Column2     DESC
1       1,2,10      Purchase, Product View, Cart Open
2       11,12,13    Checkout, Cart Add, Cart Remove
3       1,2,14      Purchase, Product View
4       20,1,10     Campaign View, Purchase, Cart Open
5       11,12,13,14 Checkout, Cart Add, Cart Remove, Cart View
```

Note:

Table1.column2[0]==table2.column1 then it will show the table2.column2 value in desc column which we added newly result table.

can we use join in this query? if yes, howwe could do in hive?

Please help on this requirement.

Thanks in Advance,
Anbu k

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Query**:

```
add jar /path/to/jars/brickhouse-0.7.1.jar;
create temporary function collect as "brickhouse.udf.collect.CollectUDAF";

select a.col1
  , collect(b.col1)
  , collect(b.col2)
from (
    select col1, exp_col2
    from db.tbl1
    lateral view explode(col2) exptbl as exp_col2 ) a
join db.tbl2 b
on b.col1=a.exp_col2
group by a.col1
```

**Output**:

```
1       [1, 2, 10]         ["Purchase","Product View","Cart Open"]
2       [11, 12, 13]       ["Checkout","Cart Add","Cart Remove"]
3       [1, 2, 14]         ["Purchase","Product View","Cart View"]
4       [1, 10, 20]        ["Purchase","Cart Open","Campaign View"]
5       [11, 12 ,13 ,14]   ["Checkout","Cart Add","Cart Remove","Cart View"]
```

Make sure to use [brickhouse collect](https://github.com/klout/brickhouse/blob/master/src/main/java/brickhouse/udf/collect/CollectUDAF.java) and not built in `collect_list()` as the latter doesn't (necessarily) preserve order.

Comment: Hi,  Thanks for your reply. I am new of this hive. I can understand the above query but can you tell me how to create temporary function collect as "brickhouse.udf.collect.CollectUDAF";. Thanks, Anbu k

Comment: can you send me the download link for jar /path/to/jars/brickhouse-0.7.1.jar; Thanks,Anbu k

Comment: It says how to build the jar on the main page of the repo.

Comment: The link which you mentioned above brickhouse collect is not open.
repo?

Comment: I want to confirm with you, table1 which means a.column2 is an array not string.
becoz i am not seeing a.cloumn2[ ] anywhere .

Comment: Okay so `column2` is an array?  Normally you'd write that as `[1, 2, 10]`. I'll modify my answer.

Comment: Yes. column2 of table1 is an array, sorry I forgot to inform you.

Thanks,
Anbu k

Comment: Feel free to mark the answer as correct if it answered your question.

Comment: @ GoBrewers ok.
can you please send the query if the table1.column2[ ] is an array.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. @ GoBrewers
can you please confirm whether my understanding is right or wrong.

1. I have  opened https://github.com/klout/brickhouse/blob/master/src/main/java/brickhouse/udf/collect/CollectUDAF.java and copy all the code and paste it in eclipse and make it as a jar (brickhouse-0.7.1.jar) and use it in hive code.

Thanks,
Anbu k

Comment: No, don't do that.  Just going to the main page https://github.com/klout/brickhouse and do steps 1 and 2 under "Getting Started"

Comment: @ GoBrewers I am really sorry. I don't understand after seeing the below steps in https://github.com/klout/brickhouse

1.Clone ( or fork ) the repo from https://github.com/klout/brickhouse 
2.Run "mvn package" from the command line.

I am initial stage learner of hadoop. In HIve I knew the basic queries.
I can understand the above command which you sent
the only thing is I want to know how to add jar file and UDF in the below query. Don't mistaken me.

So can you send the steps with screen shots document.
Thanks,
Anbu k.

Comment: send me your email (if you want to).  My profile has a link to my GitHub which has my email.

Comment: I sent a mail to you Friday itself. I am not receiving any mails from your mail id. Could you please send the steps and screenshots.

Comment: I sent it last Friday, check your spam folder

Comment: I have checked i am not receiving any mail in my spam folder too . i sent mail today again. please reply......
Thanks,
Anbu K